# how to give a div width of the whole window having a FIXED paddin or margin or border?

Tags: css

i want a div occupying the whole width of the window as well as having some padding or margin or border.
I know i can have it by giving the div a width of say 90% and having padding or margin or border of 5%. This works great but when i to reduce the window size the border or margin or padding starts shrinking. I don't want this.
So my question to the experts that how can i use a fixed padding or margin or border?

In case of narrower windows i'll rather prefer media query to detect the width and then giving another fixed padding or margin or border for a certain width.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i don't understand what you said. Can you please explain?  thanks

Comment: the 8 questions you asked on the site, you need to accept answers to them.

Comment: @darma: maksbd does not *need* to accept answers to questions if none are deemed worthy. Only 4 have answers of which none are accepted, and I can see at a glance at least 2 of those lack decent answers.

Comment: @darma thanks for your concern. And Faust thanks for your comment also. You are right Though I've asked many questions I didn't get exact answers I was seeking. From those I got, definitely I'd love to accept those answers. Why should I hesitate to respect someone what he deserves? Thanks everyone a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than percentage width, use `width:auto` then the div will expand to the width of its container, taking padding and margins into account to make it just wide enough to fit with them.

Then, if your body and html elements have width: 100%, your div with margins and padding should always just fit inside the viewport.